# STM32L476 on Nucleo, can't run at 80 Mhz

Tags: stm32, clock, nucleo

I am running the following code on a fresh & blank new project for my Nucleo-L476RG board:

```
GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
```

The clock config is default and as follow:
[image]

I am expecting to see on my oscilloscope a 80 Mhz clock but I only see 10 Mhz.
When I enable "Master Clock Output" I can see the 80 Mhz BUT my code does not seem to run at that speed.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: who told you that you can execute 2 C statements in one CPU clock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am expecting to see on my oscilloscope a 80 Mhz clock but I only see
>   10 Mhz.

Why do you expect that those two C stateements will execute in one CPU clock? Do you think it is possible? **Of course it is not**

it is translated to

```
  str r2, [r3]
  str r2, [r3, #4]
```

`str` instruction takes 2 clocks.  two of them 4 clocks. If you run from the FLASH you need to add wait states. So this will take about 8 clocks - and you see 10MHz. You can try to run from the SRAM them it will be faster.

of course it is valid only if you have those instructions one after another

```
GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
GPIOA->BRR = GPIO_PIN_4;
/*...*/
```

When you have it in the loop the loop will add additional overhead.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I knew instructions were not free but I didn't know the exact count, I was assuming one clock per instruction.